# duality in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach space. For every $x\in X,$ the non-empty duality set $\mathcal{J}(x)$ is defined as:$$\mathcal{J}(x):= \left\{j(x) \in X': \langle x, j(x)\rangle = \|x\|^{2} =  \|j(x)\|^{2} \right\}$$

where $X'$ is the dual of $X$. I want to ask if $\langle x, j(\alpha x)\rangle =\alpha\langle x, j(x)\rangle$ for all positive scalar $\alpha?$

Comment: It should follow from the fact that $\mathcal{J}(\alpha x) = \alpha \mathcal{J}(x)$

Answer (score 1):

This is trivial.  From the definition, if $j(x) \in \mathcal J(x)$ you have $\langle x, j(x) \rangle = \|x\|^2$, so for $\alpha > 0$,
$$\langle x, j(\alpha x) \rangle = \alpha^{-1} \langle \alpha x, j(\alpha x)\rangle = \alpha^{-1} \|\alpha x\|^2 = \alpha \|x\|^2 = \alpha \langle x, j(x)\rangle$$

BTW, it's true for all real scalars $\alpha$, not just positive ones.

What would be a bit less trivial would be $j(\alpha x) = \alpha j(x)$.  The problem here is that you're pretending $j$ is a function when you haven't defined it as such:  $j(x)$ could be any member of $\mathcal J(x)$, which
might have cardinality $> 1$.  But if you fix any choice of $j(x)$ for, say, $x$ in the unit sphere, then you can define $j(x) = \|x\| j(x/\|x\|)$ for $x \ne 0$, and then you will have $j(\alpha x) = \alpha j(x)$ for $\alpha > 0$.